# Kibana not showing messages from ES + Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a ES + LogStash + Kibana set up.
ES 1.1.1 is running as a Service with default configuration.

Logstash has a simple config like below:

```
input { stdin { }}
output{
elasticsearch_http {
    host => "localhost:9200"}
}
```

My aim is to see the staff I'm inputting to Console on Kibana which is configured to listen
http://someserver.com:9200 in config.js.

When I run logstash with above config file and input some words, I'm able to see them on Web page http://someserver.com:9200/_search?pretty, but my Kibana has default black screen?

What could I miss?

Comment: What do you mean with *default black screen*?

Comment: I mean a black screen with 4 buttons on the right top: Home, Save, Load, Share and logo on the right top corner. That is all. URL is http://server.com:86/kibana/#/app/dashboard/file/default.json

Comment: And you can not create anything there? Is there any error in the console of the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: No, I can't. Should I? Strange. Maybe there is some administration panel?

Comment: There is no administration panel. What version are you using? Could you show us a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Latest- Kibana 3.0.1. http://i60.tinypic.com/29p95dz.jpg

Comment: You might check your browser's JS console, just to make sure that Kibana isn't erroring out before it manages to render anything.

Comment: Console log is clean rather then error to load fontawesome - i don't think it's an issue. Also I'm using IIS as this is Windows platform

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple how to get started:

1. Start up elastic search `bin/elasticsearch` in a console window.
2. create a simple logstash config file like you have, but maybe add stdout to it... For example:

   ```
   input { stdin { }}
   output{
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       elasticsearch_http {
           host => "localhost:9200"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Start logstash with your config file: `bin/logstash -f simple.conf`
4. Type something in and make sure it gets echo'd back out:

   ```
   This is a test
   {
     "message" => "This is a test",
     "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2014-05-05T18:46:25.535Z",
         "host" => "yourhostname"
   }
   ```
5. now you can be sure that things are working, so you need to load kibana.  If you are just using a web browser (with no web server), you'll need to change the config.js file to show `elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200",` instead of the default (which builds the URL based on the web server serving the kibana content).
6. open the index.html in your browser.  You should be greeted with the Kibana Welcome Screen
7. On the right column of text, it says "Are you a logstash user"... Click on that link and create a logstash dashboard.
8. Change the time range at the top -- refresh -- every 5 seconds
9. type more into your logstash console window
10. your messages that you've typed should appear under "All Events" at the bottom of the page.

If any of this is unclear, let me know which step is giving you issues.

Comment: All of above steps work. Thanks. But I want my client to view the logs in kibana, for that I need to give him a URL. Presently we are opening local file index.html. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was in IIS. I didn't analyse where exactly, but once I set-up Apache 2.5 everything started working as well. 
Once I understand what is the issue, will update message.